# Stop diagonal selection in my Match-3 game

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a matching game where the user drags their finger over items to select them.

The problem is, i only want the user to be able to select items by dragging vertically or horizontally, not diagonally.

Here is my method that detects if the user is dragging over a item and then adds it to an array to be removed:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {



    camera.unproject(vecTemp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));



    int x = (int) vecTemp.x;
    int y = (int) vecTemp.y;

//checking to see if any objects match with the selected type and match with the position currently being dragged over
    for (GameObject object : gameObjects) {
        int ox = Math.round(object.getX());
        int oy = Math.round(object.getY());


            if (object.getType() == selectedType 
                    && x == ox
                    && y == oy
                    && !selectedObjects.contains(object,true)) {
                // You probably also want to add a condition here, to check, if the previously added object is next to the new object (x >= dx-1 && x <= dx+1 && y >= dy-1 && y <=dy+1)

 //add item to array here


                break;
            }



        }




    return true;

}
```

Anyone have any ideas of how i can change my code to not use diagonal drags?

Comment: Also note that [the quoted code is copy & pasted from here](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12304&p=55154#p55049).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already know what you need to do based on your comment. As the user slides over items and you add them to a list you need to check to make sure that the second item shares either an x or y with the first one (making it horizontal or vertical to it). Then you need to make sure the third item has the same x or y as the first two.